# Adobe air apk não roda no android 4.4.4

Tags: android, mobile, adobe-air

Estou utilizando a versão 15.0 do SDK Flex e AIR, mas mesmo assim meu aplicativo não roda no celular Moto G, que tem sua versão android de 4.4.4
Sabem dizer o que pode ser?

Answer (score 1):

Eu já descobri aqui. Era realmente o SDK que não estava no seu devido lugar.

Além de atualizar as pastas e arquivos, precisa ir em Programas e Arquivos/Adobe/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/SKDS/Selecionar algum que queria e clicar em bin.
Ao abrir a pasta, pegar os arquivos da pasta bin, dentro do ZIP e extrair lá.

Agradecimento: Google!